# Por toda vez que faço uma página no Codeigniter eu preciso colocar os links do JS, UI, VALIDADE?

Tags: codeigniter, script, view, link

Estou precisando da ajuda dos especialistas ai. Toda vez que alguma aplicação em codeigniter eu preciso colocar os links,  que normalmente ficam na head ou no footer dentro da página que criei?

Exemplo:

Eu crio uma view Usuario, e nela eu adiciono usuario e faço validação dos dados com https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js. Ai para usar essa validação, ele não consegue ler se eu colocar esse link na head ou no footer, só lê se eu colocar dentro da view addUsuario que criei.

Eu quero colocar na header ou no footer e tudo que eu fizer dentro de uma view ele vai ler o:

> script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js
>
> script src="jquery-ui.js
>
> script src="jquery.validate.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, não, você não precisa, nem deve ficar repetindo a mesma informação em todas as views (como por exemplo a importação de scripts). Na sua view usuário você deve se preocupar apenas com o que está relacionada a ela, ou seja, com o "miolo".

Há duas soluções que funcionam de maneira idêntica. Nas duas, você precisa ter pedacinhos de view para representar elementos HTML como o header e o footer, por exemplo:

`header.php` (view)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title><?=$page_title?></title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?=site_url('favicon2.ico')?>" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="icon" href="<?=site_url('favicon2.ico')?>" type="image/x-icon">        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=site_url('/css/bootstrap.min.css')?>">
    </head>
    <body>
```

`footer.php` (view)

```
        <footer class="footer">        
            <script src="<?=site_url('js/jquery.min.js')?>"></script>
            <script src="<?=site_url('js/bootstrap.min.js')?>"></script>      
            <script>
            <!-- Por exemplo um script só para uma view em específico -->
            <?=$page_script?>
            </script>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

E então, dependendo da escolha que se fizer, ou se importa isso na view, desta forma (ou seja, toda view terá um `require` no início e outro no final):

`usuario.php` (view)

```
<?php require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/header.php'); ?>
meu conteúdo da view usuário...
<?php require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/footer.php'); ?>
```

Ou então submete-se os pedacinhos de view junto no controle, desta forma:

`usuario.php` (controle)

```
public function minha_funcao() {
    // ...

    $this->load->view('header', $data);                
    $this->load->view('usuario', $data);                
    $this->load->view('footer', $data);                
}
```

Comment: Entende! Acho que utilizando desta forma $this->load->view('header', $data); resolva o problema.